# "We're sorry, but something went wrong." after deployment to Heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I've made a minor app, where a user can log in/out, be created and so forth. I'm using mySQL as the database and everything is working fine in local environment. But after I've deployed it to heroku and migrated the database and so forth, the heroku version doesn't work. I'm getting this when I tail the log:

```
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 83.233.57.240 at 2011-10-20 11:48:22 -0700
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (defaults.js isn't precompiled):
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   <head>
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 heroku[router]: GET afternoon-lightning-2154.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     <%= yield(:head) %>
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:   </head>
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2280146998680186378_39052620'
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-10-20T18:48:22+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
```

I can see that it completes the 500 error at some point, but I have no idea why. Any suggestions to this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check that you have this in config/environments/production

```
# Fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true
```

Basically your problem is that your assets are not being automatically compiled.

More info here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

Edit:

From Rails 3.1 we are going to be using the Assets pipeline. This means that you need to put all your assets (images, javascript, css) in `app/assets`. Prior to 3.1 to would put those in `public/**/*`.

In development mode Rails 3.1 is going to automatically compile ( minify both JS and CSS, transform images to base64 in some cases, etc) all your assets, creating a small, versioned package.

For a practical example, run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` in your project. Take a look at the new folder in `public/`. You can safely delete it after.

In production mode this is not automatic. You may either enable automatic compilation of the assets, or manually run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` before deployment.

More info on the Assets Pipeline
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Useful: https://github.com/dnagir/guard-rails-assets

Comment: Beautifull.... actually already tried it once, but it didn't work. The second time I did it, it did work. Can you tell me what it actually does? Thank you so much.

Comment: You're kidding me... you just fixed my css-problem as well! It didn't seem to pick up the css for some reason, but it helped compiling it. Should I do this every time I make a change or is it a one-time thing?

Comment: Your app is going to use what is in public/*. If it doesn't find the asset there, then if config.assets.compile = true it is going to recompile all assets. If that option is false, then it will throw an exception saying that it didn't found the asset. So yes, you will need to manually recompile every time your's assets changes. But if you have config.assets.compile = true then that shouldn't be necessary at all.

Comment: Also, check that you have `config.assets.compile = true` on conf/application.rb

Comment: `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` before deployment worked.