# Best practices for deploying Rails 3.2.x app to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, heroku

Are there changes to the rails config files that are commonly made to boost performance before deploying most apps to production on Heroku? Curious after reading Nerian's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840768/were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong-after-deployment-to-heroku) (summary: Heroku deployment issue solved by making "config.assets.compile = true" in config/environments/production).

Hope this isn't too general-- I'm a stack overflow newb as well. Thanks!